# In HDFS, Is the data node's mounted disk affected when it is renamed?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My hadoop cluster's has a schedule about firmware upgrade.

And I have a concern because the volume name may change due to firmware upgrade impact.

ex) sdb -> sdc , sdc ->adb

My datanode directory information is like this

HDFS namenode directory : /namenode/

HDFS datanode directory : /datanode/1~4

and datanode number is 20

```
/namenode/ -> mounted /dev/sdf
/datanode/1 -> mounted /dev/sdb
/datanode/2 -> mounted /dev/sdc
/datanode/3 -> mounted /dev/sdd
/datanode/4 -> mounted /dev/sde
```

Is HDFS integrity correct even if the disk name changes?

sdb volume can rename sdc and sdc can rename sde...

Comment: As long as the directories remain intact along with the files in it, it will not pose any problem to HDFS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tested rename and find nothing problems.